# infer (approximate) ranks or scale values from partial paired comparisons with only one rater

Tags: data-transformation, ordinal-data

I have a set of items $10$ $(A, B, .., J)$ and paired comparisons between a subset of those items, with a value of $1$ indicating that the column item is ranked *higher* than the row item and a value of $0$ if it is ranked *lower*. The matrix is incomplete as each item is only compared against the *preceding three items* in my case:

[image]

Hence, $B > A$, $C > A$, $C < B$, ...
**I would like to get scale values or ranks for these items, so the inferred order/values resemble the matrix relations as close as possible.** This is somewhat akin to [Thurstone LCJ scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_comparative_judgment) but here I have **one rater** only, so I am not sure, if it is applicable. Also, we only have partial data, not the full matrix.

How can I go about it?

**Edit:** to make it clearer what I mean by scaling: Either assigning ranks or other values to the items that justify the empirical matrix.